# Salesforce querying standard object with custom controller

Tags: controller, salesforce

I'm trying to populate a drop down list in a Salesforce page with the following code:

```
public List<SelectOption> getContacts()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(Contacts c : [SELECT Name FROM Contacts])
    {
        if(c.Name != NULL)
        options.add(new SelectOption(c.Name));
    }
    return options;
}
```

but I'm getting an error on save: "sObject type Contacts is not supported". Now Contacts is a standard object I know that much even though I'm a Salesforce noob. Is this something syntactical I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `Contact` rather than `Contacts`. Object API names are typically singular.

```
for ( Contact c : [SELECT Name FROM Contact] )
```

Comment: Just found that out. Thanks. I also found the SelectOption constructor demand 2 inputs, so having c.Name alone will cause an error. I added c.ID.

Comment: @axon if this anwered helped you, you may mark it as such by clicking the V icon on the left of the content.